# Check My Math (price per unit)

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I am trying to do some calculations to figure out how much something would be in $100$ grams, $1$ pound, $1$ ounce.

Many times I am at the grocery store and want to know if that item selling for $\$10$ is cheaper then the bulk item at $\$.85 / 100$ grams or whatever

[image]

My formulas are these:
[image: formulas]

P.S

I really have no clue what Tag to use.

Edit

Ok, so I redone the numbers and added Kilogram field.

formulas are these:
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only have two wrong for the Price in Ounce for Grams and Pounds:

$39\ g \rightarrow \$0.59$

$1\ g \rightarrow \dfrac{\$0.59}{39}$

$1\ g = 0.035274\ oz \rightarrow \dfrac{\$0.59}{39}$

$1\ oz \rightarrow \dfrac{\$0.59}{39} \times\dfrac{1}{0.035274}$

This makes the formula become `=A16/(B16*0.035274)`

Multiplying by $28.3495 \frac{g}{oz}$ is actually getting the price for $28.3495 g$.

And the next one is similar;

$4\ lbs \rightarrow \$5.00$

$1\ lbs \rightarrow \dfrac{\$5.00}{4}$

$1\ lbs=16\ oz \rightarrow \dfrac{\$5.00}{4}$

$1\ oz \rightarrow \dfrac{\$5.00}{4} \times\dfrac{1}{16}$

Comment: I thought the ounce ones might be wrong. I thought if I times it by 28.3495g it would give me per ounce since that many grams equal 1 ounce(but the number look way to high). You first found out how many ounces there where from that amount of grams, then you divided the cost by that many ounces to find cost per ounce correct?

Comment: @xiao That's correct. It's step by step and I don't think you can make mistakes that way. Once you get the grasp of it, you can easily do the others faster ^^ But really, the British quantities are awful to work with. I prefer the metric system by far :)

Comment: Ya usually better to work step by step. I never work with ounces except I think when I go to the States shopping, I think they have it in ounces. Ya will do some more trials to get a better understand it but the end goal is that I am going to make an mobile app to do it for me. I forgot kilograms so I will post an update once I am finished working through it

Comment: @xiao Those seem good. By the way, is it normal that the Price/Pound table has \$6.59 for 1 kg instead of \$5.00 like the others?

Comment: Ah yea I changed it because that was the example I got from a tutorial when looking up to see if I did it right. This way I knew the formula would be right and then I could see that $2.99 / pound equals $6.59/kg and 6.59/kg equals $2.99 / pound.

Comment: @xiao Oh okay ^^ All's good then!